# Python Max function - Finding highest value in a dictionary

Tags: python, lambda, max

My question is about finding highest value in a dictionary using max function.

I have a created dictionary that looks like this:

```
cc_GDP = {'af': 1243738953, 'as': 343435646, etc}
```

I would like to be able to simply find and print the highest GDP value for each country.

My best attempt having read through similar questions is as follows (I'm currently working through the Python crash course book at which the base of this code has been taken, note the get_country_code function is simply providing 2 letter abbreviations for the countries in the GDP_data json file):

```
#Load the data into a list
filename = 'gdp_data.json'
with open(filename) as f:
    gdp_data = json.load(f)

cc_GDP` = {}
for gdp_dict in gdp_data:
    if gdp_dict['Year'] == 2016:
        country_name = gdp_dict['Country Name']
        GDP_total = int(gdp_dict['Value'])
        code = get_country_code(country_name)
        if code:
            cc_GDP[code] = int(GDP_total)

print(max(cc_GDP, key=lambda key: cc_GDP[key][1]))
```

This provides the following error `'TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable'`

Note if leaving out the [1] in the print function, this does provide the highest key which relates to the highest value, but does not return the highest value itself which is what I wish to achieve.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you currently extract the key of the country that has the highest value with this line:

```
country_w_highest_val = max(cc_GDP, key=lambda key: cc_GDP[key]))
```

You can of course just look that up in the dictionary again:

```
highest_val = cc_GDP[contry_w_highest_val]
```

But simpler, disregard the keys completely, and just find the highest value of all values in the dictionary:

```
highest_val = max(cc_GDP.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
print max(cc_GDP.values())
```

That will give you the highest value but not the key.

Answer (score 1):

The error is being cause because you need to look at the entire dictionary, not just one item.  remove the `[1]` and then use the following line:

```
print(cc_GDP[max(cc_GDP, key=lambda key: cc_GDP[key])])
```

Your code currently just returns the dictionary key.  You need to plug this key back into the dictionary to get the GDP.

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy `.items()` method of `dict` to get `key-value` pairs (`tuple`s) and process it following way:

```
cc_GDP = {'af': 1243738953, 'as': 343435646}
m = max(list(cc_GDP.items()), key=lambda x:x[1])
print(m) #prints ('af', 1243738953)
```

Output `m` in this case is 2-`tuple`, you might access key `'af'` via `m[0]` and value `1243738953` via `m[1]`.